# Can't get Parse.com PFUser data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a UITableView that is populated with games that a user is currently playing. I have a Pointer column in the Game table called Turn that points to a PFUser in the User table. Instead of setting the cell text to the objectID of the Turn value, I'd like to instead set it to the player's first name, which is stored in the User table.

The problem is that when I println the Turn pointer object, it only contains the objectID and I can't pull the first_name. Here's my code:

```
 let object = gameResults[indexPath.row]

 let user = object["turn"] as! PFUser

 let userString = "\(object.first_name)"

 cell.textLabel?.text = userString

 return cell
```

The cell text just reads "nil". How do I get the user data from the User table that relates to the Turn pointer column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer column data are not included by default when using PFQuery.

Do this to tell your query to include the pointer data:

```
yourQuery.includeKey("turn")
```

This will get the user data from the user table and include it in the PFObject obtained.

**UPDATE:**

To get the `first_name` field (or any field for that matter), the syntax is:

```
let userSting = user["first_name"] as String
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added that to the query that is returning the GameResults but it still returns nil. I created a gist of the view controller. Can you please take a look and tell me where I went wrong? Thanks!
https://gist.github.com/jtansley/95222c75c211f3f18356

Comment: Getting an error "OR queries do not support sub-queries with includes". Hmm...any way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Use `includeKey` only for the final query. I think the problem was the missing `@`. See update above.

Comment: When I added the @ it asked me to place a "," . `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`. I don't think the @ is required for swift

Comment: Right, this is Swift...my bad. :(

Comment: Is the field name `turn` correct? Cross check from Parse's data browser.

Comment: Yep, turn exists with data type Pointer to _User table

Comment: What do you get when you nslog `user` after the `let user = object["turn"] as! PFUser` line?

Comment: I had to delete a lot of the columns since it took too many chars, but as you can see it does get "turn":

`<PFUser: 0x7fcd8972aa10, objectId: aElMSjGRxM, localId: (null)> {
    accepted =     (
    );
    "first_name" = James;
    image = <ffd8ffe0 ...d405ccff d9>;
    location = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7fcd8972a170, latitude: 0.000000, longitude: 0.000000>";
    );
    turn = "<PFUser: 0x7fcd8972a240, objectId: aElMSjGRxM>";
    username = MJUW5pylODSJoiSaR5sZANq86;
}`

Comment: I think the interesting thing is that the "turn" column in the log only shows a PFUser with an objectID and a username. It doesn't seem to pull any of the other user attributes. Since user DOES seem to have "first_name" pulled from object, I would think you'd be able to just say user.first_name, but I get an error `PFUser does not have a member named first_name`. This is so confusing. The data is right there but I can't use it :/

Comment: The associated data is being shown in the log... image, location... But yeah, that's not how you access the data fields. See update above.

Comment: YES! `object["first_name"]` returned nil but when I changed it to `user["first_name"]` it worked!! Thanks again for helping me throughout the last 24 hours. I can't thank you enough.